# how to use cast and case together in teradata sql assistant

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to cast col agent as small integer  and nee to bring absolute value of col agent.
I know how to do separate but not together.

```
select     
cast (a.AGENT as smallint) as agent,
abs (a.AGENT)
from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the `cast()`, I think:

```
select cast(a.AGENT as smallint) as agent, abs(cast(a.AGENT as smallint))
from Table;
```

Comment: @user3803261 . . . That sounds like a different question and questions should be asked as questions not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a single column:

```
abs(cast (a.AGENT as smallint)) as agent
```

Comment: Can you help with following
case  a.contract when  'Y' then 'Authorized'when 'N' then ' Suspended' end
need to cast contract to varchar 20  from char 1

and 

case a.netting WHEN 'Y' THEN '1' ELSE  '0' END
cast netting to byte int from char 10.

Thanks in advance